# How to find the column that contains a particular sub-column/nested column in 3D-Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, 3d

So I have the following 3D Pandas Dataframe, `new`:

```
  unique     cat     numerical    
       c   f   b   d         a   e
0      2   5   1   3         0   4
1      8  11   7   9         6  10
2     14  17  13  15        12  16
```

I want to find which 'shallower' column contains the 'deeper' column 'd', which would be 'cat'. I'm really new to Pandas but after staring at `new.columns` for a while:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['cat', 'numerical', 'unique'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']],
           labels=[[2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1], [2, 5, 1, 3, 0, 4]])
```

I finally figured this really seemingly long-winded, extremely nested, convoluted way of doing it, which does get me `'cat'`:

```
print(
    new.columns.levels[0][\
    new.columns.labels[0][\
    pd.Index(new.columns.labels[1]).get_loc(\
    pd.Index(new.columns.levels[1]).get_loc('d'))]]
)
```

I'm basically getting the position of 'd' in the second array under levels (let's call it pos1), then finding the position (pos2) of that value (pos1) in the second array under labels, and then finding the value (val1) in the first array under 'labels' using that position (pos2), and finally finding what the column name is in the first array under 'levels' using the position val1.

So my question is, is there a better, 'proper' way of doing all this? Thanks.

P.S. on a separate note, all this is actually just so that I can search column 'd' without knowing which 'shallower' column it belongs to:

```
row = (new.loc[new['cat']['d'] == 9])
```

such that I get:

```
  unique     cat     numerical    
       c   f   b   d         a   e
1      8  11   7   9         6  10
```

So if there was a way to do that, this whole question would be avoided.(I'm new to stack overflow too do I have to put this in a new question or smt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `swaplevel`

But you aren't guaranteed to have a unique column, so I force the issue with `iloc[:, 0]`

```
new[new.swaplevel(0, 1, 1).d.iloc[:, 0].eq(9)]

  unique     cat    numerical    
       c   f   b  d         a   e
1      8  11   7  9         6  10
```

---

#### `xs`

Same caveat about no guarantee of uniqueness

```
new[new.xs('d', 1, 1).iloc[:, 0].eq(9)]

  unique     cat    numerical    
       c   f   b  d         a   e
1      8  11   7  9         6  10
```

---

#### `IndexSlice`

```
new[new.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'd']].iloc[:, 0].eq(9)]

  unique     cat    numerical    
       c   f   b  d         a   e
1      8  11   7  9         6  10
```

---

#### `levels` and `labels`

My version of the convoluted approach

```
a0, a1 = new.columns.labels
b0, b1 = new.columns.levels

j = b1.get_loc('d')
i = a0[(a1 == j).argmax()]
t = (b0[i], b1[j])

new[new[t] == 9]

  unique     cat    numerical    
       c   f   b  d         a   e
1      8  11   7  9         6  10
```

Comment: by "no guaranteed unique column" do you mean 2 or more columns with the same name? 

also, your swaplevel approach actually doesn't work for me as my column names are actually survey questions with spaces and full stops. is the approach of using swaplevel simply limited in that way?

Comment: @NathanTew it’s not swaplevel. It’s my use of.d instead of [‘d’] when accessing afterwards